# Get array without element at index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I implemented a function to get a shallow copy of an array without a specific element (using its index).

But I have to call three methods to achieve this. Is there a better way of doing this?

```js
const arrayWithoutElementAtIndex = function (arr, index) {
    return arr.slice(0, index).concat(arr.slice(index + 1))
}

arrayWithoutElementAtIndex([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64], 3) // [1, 2, 4, 16, 32, 64]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about a regular [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```js
const arrayWithoutElementAtIndex = function (arr, index) {
  return arr.filter(function(value, arrIndex) {
    return index !== arrIndex;
  });
}
document.write(arrayWithoutElementAtIndex([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64], 3)); // [1, 2, 4, 16, 32, 64]
```

This would mean you only have a single function and it returns a new array instance.

Comment: Ah yeah! The filter... Duh!
I wish es6 had implemented non-fat arrow notation, or at least provided a `fn` keyword. Writing `function` everywhere makes one-liner so hard to fit in 80 characters.

Comment: @user1534422 with one arrow, You could do it this way: `const arrayWithoutElementAtIndex = (arr, index, newArr = [...arr]) => (newArr.splice(index,1), newArr)`, you can see my answer edition. Excuse my english

Comment: code golf: `const filter = (arr, index) => arr.filter((_, i) => index !== i);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 operation using [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), but won't be looking that nice

```js
'use strict'

const arrayWithoutElementAtIndex = function(arr, index) {
  var ret = arr.slice(); //make a copy
  ret.splice(index, 1); //remove the item from given index
  return ret; //return the copy
}

var array = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64];
var array2 = arrayWithoutElementAtIndex(array, 3) // [1, 2, 4, 16, 32, 64]

snippet.log(array)
snippet.log(array2)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid splice because you always end up with three times more lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

With lodash:

```
_(this.state.additionalOwners, index).splice(index, 1).value())
```